# D365 SLA CUSTOMER SERVICE not working as expected not timer shown

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I have designed a SLA using web client(old interface) to update case priority.

*when created on contains data and case title contains data.*

This SLA will change priority from default to High when case is not resolved in 24 hours

SLA design steps-

Applicable when- createdon contains data

success when- case title contains data

warning time -30 minutes

failure time -1 hour

kpi - first response by

*PROBLEM*- when designed using old interface first response by timer shows as 23h:59m: 59s

BUT

**I have designed same SLA in UCI interface and first response timer does not shows intead as soon as condition met it shows succeeded** and no wait timer is shows as it is when designed in old interface.

**I have also tried to migrate same sla in uci from Old interface but problem remains the same.**

i appreciate any help provided. Thank you!!